# Workday Function and Data validation in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

```
    Dim Deadline As Date
   
    Deadline = CDate(planilhaOrigem.Range("D30").Value)
    

    
    Dim dataAtual As Date
    Dim dataLimite As Date
    Dim intervalo As Integer
   
    Select Case Period
        Case "Weekly"
            intervalo = 7 
        Case "Monthly"
            intervalo = 30 
        Case "Bimonthly"
            intervalo = 60 
        Case "Quarterly"
            intervalo = 90 
        Case "Annual"
            intervalo = 365 
        Case Else
            intervalo = 0 
    End Select
    
    
    If Info1 <> "" And Info2 <> "" And Info3 <> "" Info4 <> "" And Info5 <> "" And Info6 <> "" And Info7 <> "" And Deadline "" Then
        
        dataLimite = DateSerial(2024, 12, 31)
        
        dataAtual = Deadline
    
        If Period = "On Demand" Then
            tabelaDestino.ListRows.Add
            With tabelaDestino.ListRows(tabelaDestino.ListRows.Count).Range
                .Cells(1, correspondenciaColunas("Deadline")).Value = dataAtual
                .Cells(1, correspondenciaColunas("Info12")).Value = Info12
                .Cells(1, correspondenciaColunas("Deadline")).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
            End With
        Else
            Do While dataAtual <= dataLimite
                tabelaDestino.ListRows.Add
                With tabelaDestino.ListRows(tabelaDestino.ListRows.Count).Range
                    .Cells(1, correspondenciaColunas("Deadline")).Value = dataAtual
                    .Cells(1, correspondenciaColunas("Info12")).Value = Info12
                    .Cells(1, correspondenciaColunas("Deadline")).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
                End With
    
                dataAtual = DateAdd("d", intervalo, dataAtual)
                proximoID = proximoID + 1
            Loop
        End If
```

Context: I'm creating a form where people enter information, click a button, and this information goes to another worksheet as if it were a database. I'm facing two issues. The main one is related to the Deadline input. I would like to set it in work days, but I don't know how. I tried using AI, but it didn't work. If the person selects "monthly" starting from today, some months will fall on a Saturday or Sunday. What I need is for the code to automatically set the nearest work day for that month. For example, if today is 09/18 and it's a Monday, but next month falls on a Sunday, it should automatically set it to Monday. The second problem is that I'm unable to apply data validation to the "deadline." It gives an error in this part here: " "" And Deadline "" Then." If I delete " "" And Deadline "" in If, the code run normal, but if i put, than goes wrong.
I've tried anonymizing a lot of data, so there may be some variable naming errors. Please ignore that; I only changed it to share here.

Comment: Did you mean `And Deadline <> ""`?

Comment: Yes! When I use ""And Deadline " Then", my code does not work. If I code only ""And info7" then", my code run normally. Idk when I code Deadline in the validation, does not work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following Function that will return the next business day:

```
Function GetNextBusDay(myDate) As Date

' Function retruns the Next Business Date receing 'myDate' as initial Date

Dim i As Long
Dim TempDate As Date


For i = 0 To 2
    TempDate = DateAdd("d", i, myDate)
    
    If Weekday(TempDate, vbMonday) <= 5 Then
        Exit For
    End If
Next i

GetNextBusDay = TempDate

End Function
```

Comment: The code that I tried was very similar to this one. The issue that I had was, if the deadline was not in a work day, the code jumped to the other month, until fall in a work day... I will try this one, ty.